# Prevent IDs with Record.friendly.find param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm using FriendlyId and Rails.

I would like to support finding by the slug:
`https://example.com/restaurants/plaza-diner`

But NOT support finding by its ID:
`https://example.com/restaurants/23`

I'm using `Restaurant.friendly.find(params[:id])` which by default does support both. How can I make it so retrieving by IDs is not supported?

Using `find_by(slug: params[:id])` is not an option, as it skips FriendlyId's internals and does not support historical slugs for example.

I could check to see if `params[:id]` is an integer and raise a `ActiveRecord:RecordNotFound`, but that seems convoluted. Is there a simpler approach?

Relevant file:
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/819c0b111b0f722809c0a13ad025c5191a278f85/lib/friendly_id/finders.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Restaurant.friendly.find_by_friendly_id(params[:id])`.

> Finds exclusively by the friendly id, completely bypassing original `find`.

See:

- [docs](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/FriendlyId/FinderMethods.html#find_by_friendly_id-instance_method)
- [source](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/819c0b111b0f722809c0a13ad025c5191a278f85/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb#L37)

Comment: 10-10-2022 and you helped me.